# mysql database keeps returning null

Tags: php, mysql

```
if ($con->connect_error) 
{
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM Accounts WHERE acccount_num ='$accountNum'";

$result = $con->query($sql);
//$row = $result->fetch_row();

$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
print (json_encode($row));

$con->close();
```

This is my php code for connecting to the database where it is failing. I checked the field names in the actual database and I also checked all my code in the java project where my code is actually using the database. Really new to the whole concept of databases and PHP.

Comment: Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` to the top of your script. This will force any `mysqli_` errors to
generate an Exception that you can see on the browser and other errors will also be visible on your browser.

Comment: What is `$accountNum` set to?

Comment: Are you using the `mysqli_` or `PDO` database extension

Comment: Your script is at risk of [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Have a look at what happened to [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) Even
[if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Answer (score -1):

Use this

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Accounts WHERE acccount_num =$accountNum";
```

instead of

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Accounts WHERE acccount_num ='$accountNum'";
```

Comment: MySQL will automatically convert strings to numbers, this won't make a difference.

Answer (score -1):

> Try this or maybe you have an extra c in acccount_num.

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM `accounts` WHERE `acccount_num` ='".$accountNum."'"
```